# Error while running the collectstatic on django FileNotFoundError:

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

So I am running the command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and I am getting an error, I am pretty sure it is because I have some setting off inside my settings.py.
First I will attach a picture, so everyone can see the tree of my documents and then the error itself.

Any idea of what I did wrong? Thank you.

Picture:
[Image with the tree of files and settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiRBI.png)

My settings.py

```
# on the top
import os

# on the bottom
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

The error is the following:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project> python manage.py collectstatic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle 
    collected = self.collect()
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 109, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 130, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\utils.py", line 23, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 316, in listdir
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\lenil\\Documents\\Development\\Personal Projects\\the-journey\\thejourney_project\\thejourney_project\\static'     
(env) PS C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project>
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: can show the print of this  `python manage.py findstatic `

Comment: Hi @BelhadjerSamir, after running the command, this is what I get.

```
(env) PS C:\Users\lenil\Documents\Development\Personal Projects\the-journey\thejourney_project> python manage.py findstatic
usage: manage.py findstatic [-h] [--first] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color] [--skip-checks] staticfile [staticfile ...]
manage.py findstatic: error: Enter at least one label.
````

Answer (score 0):

The image you've attached of your project structure does not show a directory for `static` or `staticfiles`. You need to move those directories up, or change your paths to map to those directories.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to redeploy and this time used these settings. It worked for me.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects/static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I also had to change the Procfile to this

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

The whole steps:

```
First make sure you have requirements.txt and Procfile
In Procfile, the contents were like this
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
And run python manage.py collectstatic just to make sure no errors from collectstatic
Then these commands in cmd
heroku login
Then login from browser
git init
heroku git:remote -a app_name
git add .
git commit -am "first commit"
git push heroku main         -------------– or masterher
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku open
```